# Prisma DATABASE_URL validation error in a Next.js application using t3 stack

Tags: sql-server, next.js, prisma

I'm building a full-stack Next.js application using the t3 stack, and I'm encountering an error when trying to configure my Prisma ORM to connect to a SQL Server database using the DATABASE_URL. The DATABASE_URL I'm providing is as follows:

**sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;database=demo;user=Username;password=Password;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true**

However, when I use this URL, I get the following error message:
**❌ Invalid environment variables: { DATABASE_URL: [ 'Invalid url' ] }**

> Schema for validating the env variable is DATABASE_URL:
>
> ```
> z.string()
>   .url()
>   .refine(
>     (str) => !str.includes("YOUR_MYSQL_URL_HERE"),
>     "You forgot to change the default URL"
>   )
> ```

It seems like there's a validation error occurring for the DATABASE_URL. I'm not sure how to resolve this issue or what might be causing it.
please help me understand why I'm getting this validation error, and how I can correctly configure the DATABASE_URL for my SQL Server connection in a Next.js application using Prisma?

Edit : This Connection String is working for me:

```
sqlserver://Server-Address;database=Database_Name;user=Username;password=Password;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
```